# Group Policy - Drive Mapping Preferences - slow login even if only using Computer Config side

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

We are having some users with very slow login times, up to 20 minutes, but only for a handful of users.

I've narrowed it down to a particular GPO that does nothing but Drive Mapping Preferences.

I tried to disable the User Configuration portion of the GPO that does the drive mappings to see if that would speed up the issue, but even just the Computer Configuration portion being enabled causes the slowdown.  The GPO is applied at a root OU that ends up where their computer and user account get it applied as inherited.

Here's the Computer Configuration portion of the GPO:

```
Policy                                                         Setting       Comment 

Configure Drive Maps preference extension policy processing    Enabled  
Allow processing across a slow network connection              Enabled 
Process even if the Group Policy objects have not changed      Enabled 
Background priority                                            Idle
```

If I disable both the Computer and the User Configuration in this GPO then logins are back to 5-10 seconds for these users.

I've looked up what these do, but I'm wondering if they somehow do some kind of loopback processing or something?  I don't understand why the login times would still be slow if the entire User Configuration is disabled.  What exactly is happening with the Computer Configuration portion above that would cause the policy to hang and a logon to sit there for 10-20 minutes even if the user side is disabled that actually does all the drive mapping preferences?

Comment: Sound pretty severe to be this, but network timeouts trying to enumerate and/or access the drives to be mapped?

Comment: @HopelessN00b I would agree, but I don't get why if I disable the User Config side of the GPO that enumerates/accesses the drives, why it is still slow.  I'm curious what the Computer Config side does on a computer OU that would force it to still enumerate through the User Config side.

Comment: BTW, cleaning up the invalid mappings in the GPO fixed the issue of the slow login times.  So you are right on what it is doing...I just don't understand why it would with the User Config side disabled.